# How can I get the serial monitor in vs code to automatically connect and disconnect when uploading to my arduino?

Tags: visual-studio-code, arduino, platformio

I am using an Arudino Nano with VS Code and PlatformIO.
When developing. I want to streamline the process so that when I press 1 hotkey.
It will automatically disconnect the Serial Monitor. Build. Upload. Then reconnect the Serial Monitor.

I can partially do it with the "Upload and Monitor" project task:

[image]

However, it connects to the serial via the Terminal which means I can't send commands like I do with the serial monitor:

[image]

If I connect the serial monitor manually. It does not automatically disconnect so that it can do the upload.

How can I set up vs code with platform io to build, upload, and reconnect the serial monitor with a single hotkey?

Answer (score 1):

As of VS Code extension `PlatformIO IDE v3.3.1`, there's a built-in setting called `Auto Close Serial Monitor` which is enabled by default. However, a limitation is that there's no direct option to automatically reopen the serial monitor after an upload.

An alternative approach is to utilize the `Upload and Monitor` option. The challenge here is that if you wish to use this option again, it prompts you to either `Terminate Task` or `Restart Task`, leading to potential time consumption in the long run.

To address this and to answer your question, you can extend the functionality of the VS Code `PlatformIO Toolbar` by following these steps:

1. Open your VS Code settings.
2. Look for the `Platformio-id: toolbar` configuration.
3. Click on `Edit in settings.json`. This action will generate a setting in your VS Code configuration named `platformio-ide.toolbar`, which will also be visible in the bottom left bar of your VS Code interface.
4. Inside the JSON array of `platformio-ide.toolbar`, insert the following JSON object to add an extra setting to your toolbar:

```
...
    {
      "text": "$(arrow-up)",
      "tooltip": "PlatformIO: Upload and Monitor",
      "commands": [
        "workbench.action.terminal.kill",
        "platformio-ide.uploadAndMonitor"
      ]
    }
...
```

5. Feel free to modify the `text` and `tooltip` according to your preference, then save your changes.

Comment: upload and monitor uses the terminal instead of the serial monitor tab